# How certain is the Latin origin of Albanian ”gënjej” (to lie) from Latin (ingannō<ganniō)?

Tags: etymology, latin, albanian

Albanian word [*gënjej*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/g%C3%ABnjej#Etymology) ("to lie") is considered to be of Latin origin — from Vulgar Latin *ingannō*, from Latin *ganniō*... These are the only details I could find. Wiktionary gives no scholarly sources. I would like to know more: how certain is that etymology?

The level of certitude of that origin is important in the economy of [a different question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/21565/3284) that I will not develop here, so I want to know what that level is.

What are the etymological transformation/evolution rules involved and how do they apply here?